# C++ Core Guidelines Checker REALLY slow on small project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, static-analysis

I'm using an A8-5600K so I'm used to waiting a bit for CPU tasks to complete - nothing too bad but as far as CPUs go it's not the greatest. 12GB RAM, running very latest Visual Studio 2017 (15.6.6 iirc) as of this morning.

I'm wanting to run static analysis simply because I believe it could save me time chasing edge cases and bugs while also making the code look nicer. I've got a relatively small project (single file, 5000 lines) which uses WxWidgets, OpenCV, STD, Chrono, Threads, Windows, and probably a few other things. I'm only running a single check (Style) as I figured it would be faster than running every check. It's been running for an hour and in the meantime I've got a CPU that's more or less tapped out and can't compile anything.

I presume by this point that the Checker is getting through my code in no time and spending ages trying to tell me how to fix OpenCV or something. I understand that without knowing how OpenCV works the Checker might find it difficult understanding some stuff that's going on in my code.

What can I do? Is the Checker simply not meant for consumer-grade CPUs ? If I ran this overnight would it finish? Does the number of rules have that much of an effect or should I just have them all checked for (ie 95% crawling my project, 5% analysis)?

Also, the posts I've seen in regard to 3rd Party Libraries seem content with simply filtering out the warnings post-check (words on the blackboard are written but merely erased afterward so to speak) - this likely won't speed things up for me.